# WPF: How do I implement a stretch transform?

Tags: wpf, transform, stretch

I am trying to implement an effect that will stretch a polygon along a line from its center point to the mouse location. I've tried various approaches with a `SkewTransform` and the planar angle between those two points but that isn't giving me what I want.

I am kind of assuming I'll have to go the `MatrixTransform` route but my linear algebra is pretty rusty.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) and just apply it in one direction then combine it with a [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.aspx) if the direction you need to stretch in isn't just plain x or y, or take a look at the [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stretch.aspx) property on the shape.

There's a good article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TransformationsIntro.aspx) that has some examples.

MSDN also has some [reference material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx).